# URLDownloadToFile downloading half of file

Tags: c#, .net

I using URLDownload to dowload a file, i downloaded 5 files(zip),2 of them damaged ,and the first one i tried to re-download(2-3 times) and it works the second one after 20(times) stiil dameged,it seems it stop download before it finished.

**Damaged** *(i download this file manually and zip open fine, and size 75kb ,and the file that i downloaded from URLDownload  have 11kb sow you see the difference and know that it is not full download\damaged )*

My code

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 URLDownloadToFile(Int32 pCaller, string szURL, string szFileName, Int32 dwReserved, Int32 lpfnCB);

 int response = URLDownloadToFile(0, Link, FilePath, 0, 0);

       if (response == 0)
        {
      lsUtils.WriteToLog("File  " + FileName + " downloaded.", true);
      int zipTry = 10;
      if (!isValidZip(FilePath))
                 {
  clsUtils.WriteToLog("Attempting to re-download damaged file   " + FileName, true);
  while (!isValidZip(FilePath) && zipTry > 1)
        {
  clsUtils.WriteToLog("File  " + FileName + " Zip file damaged.", true);
  response = URLDownloadToFile(0, Link, FilePath, 0, 0);
                                            zipTry--;

                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use WebClient?

Comment: this files is in the bank site after login/password,i can't just insert url and download  this files.(i tried it dosn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Why use URLDownloadToFile? That's an extremely round-about way of downloading a file in .NET.

Instead, here's a simple example in .NET 4.5+:

```
async Task DownloadAndSaveAsync(string url, string filePath)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    // Was the request successful?
    if (response == null || !response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return;

    using (var file = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
}
```

If you don't have .NET 4.5+, you're going to have to use `HttpWebRequest`, but it's still much better than doing a P/Invoke.

As for the original URLDownloadToFile issue, I'd guess it isn't blocking, so it is still downloading on the background at the time you check if the zip is valid, and then you overwrite it with the second attempt etc. So it's not that it doesn't go through the download - you're not waiting long enough. But again, that's just a guess. You shouldn't be creating dependencies on Internet Explorer unless you really need them :)

Comment: i am using 4.0,and i  think HttpWebRequest won't work  because this files is in the bank site after login/password, and you need to have cookies + permission before start download them,you  can't just insert url and download this files.

Comment: @user3567884 Well, you can use cookies and credentials in `HttpWebRequest` too. In any case, depending on IE to do the download for you probably isn't the best usage (in a way, that's pretty much a security hole in IE). But if you want to stick with it, just use the callback method to know when the file is actually downloaded. It's downloaded asynchronously, so when you're checking, it most likely hasn't finished downloading. The callback (`lpfnCB`) will tell you when that happens. Unless I'm mistaken. But you can try it easily - run the method and just wait a bit before checking the file.

Comment: You made me to Install VS 2012. :) bey bey vs 2010

Comment: I installed 2012 4.5 ,but it is not working,i can't get to url,because i conected to webSite with watIn(dll)  browser ,and the old function URLDownloadToFile some how be able to use cookies from this var Browser by it self and download files,but DownloadAndSaveAsync not work here.